# How to create circuit breaker for cloud run services?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-cloud-run

I am trying to understand how we can create circuit breakers for cloud run services,Unlike in GKE we are using istio kind of service mesh how we implement same thing cloud Run ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GKE you'd [set up a circuit breaker](https://cloud.google.com/traffic-director/docs/configure-advanced-traffic-management#circuit-breaking) to prevent overloading your legacy backend systems from a surge in requests.

To accomplish the same on Cloud Run or Cloud Functions, you can set a [maximum number of instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances). From that documentation:

> Specifying maximum instances in Cloud Run allows you to limit the scaling of your service in response to incoming requests, although this maximum setting can be exceeded for a brief period due to circumstances such as [traffic spikes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#spikes). Use this setting as a way to control your costs or to limit the number of connections to a backing service, such as to a database.

Comment: hi @Frank van Puffelen,
How can we do a circuit breaker in this case?
For example, if your service is unavailable for a certain reason, after 5 consecutive requests I  want to break the circuit for accepting new requests and show some error page, is it possible at infra level?

Comment: Clients should implement [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

Comment: As a part of code right?, at so infra level we can not do anything  as it is managed service( cloud run )